# Making a link work with no text in Sitecore

Tags: c#, sitecore

I am having a problem with how to display a link in Sitecore. Currently I have three fields that I use: Name, Title and Link. All three of these fields are within a div tag, so...

```
 <div class="container">
      <div class="name"><sc:FieldRenderer ID="ColumnName" FieldName="Name" runat="server" /></div>
      <div class="title"><sc:FieldRenderer ID="ColumnTitle" FieldName="Title" runat="server" /></div>
      <div class="link"><sc:FieldRenderer ID="ColumnLink" FieldName="Link" runat="server" /></div>
 </div>
```

For regular view, the link tag is being displayed as just text (that is written in Sitecore) but when it switches to mobile view, the container becomes the link with the Name and Title as the only thing showing and taking away what is in the Link field. My problem is how do I make the container the same link as the one that displays as text in desktop view? Is there a way have the text not be displayed and put an overlay container ontop of everything but just have the background as transparency to make the container go to the same link? For the backend, I just used a Listview that contained everything to make the fields show:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Item item = this.DataSourceItem;

        lvContains.DataSource = ((MultilistField)item.Fields["Columns"]).GetItems();
        lvContains.DataBind();
    }

    protected void lvContains_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
        {
            Item item = (Item)e.Item.DataItem;
            ((FieldRenderer)e.Item.FindControl("ColumnName")).Item = item;
            ((FieldRenderer)e.Item.FindControl("ColumnTitle")).Item = item;
            ((FieldRenderer)e.Item.FindControl("ColumnLink")).Item = item;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using a responsive design, for the mobile/tablet breakpoints you can add some additional CSS properties to make the link the full height/width of the parent container and hide the text:

```css
.container { border: solid 1px red; position: relative; }
.name { border: solid 1px blue; }
.title { border: solid 1px green; }
.link a { 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    color: transparent;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
      <div class="name">Item Name</div>
      <div class="title">Item Title</div>
      <div class="link"><a href="#">Item Link</a></div>
 </div>
```

If you are not using a responsive design, and using device detection, then you can add an additional CSS class to the link and modify the css to match:

```
.link a.mobile {
  ...
}
```

And add the CSS Class in code behind:

```
((FieldRenderer)e.Item.FindControl("ColumnLink")).CssClass = "mobile";
```

Comment: Thanks,I'll try this out tomorrow